# Changed /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Now can't get to SU. Am I screwed?

Tags: ssh, root, amazon-ec2

To allow one of my users ssh access I added the line

```
AllowUsers user
```

to my sshd_config. I gave the box a reboot and attempted to ssh back in as superuser. I was unable to do so. I have my keys- both public and private locally, but I'm guessing the change in the config is preventing me logging in.  However I can get into the `user` account. This is just a EC2 VM, so there's no desktop trick I can try.

`user` has just standard permissions

Comment: If I am out of luck, I understand :(

Comment: If you can get in as `user`, do so and escalate yourself to root with `su` or `sudo`, then leave your config alone realizing you accidentally followed best practices by disallowing remote root logins (though not explicitly, so maybe fix that).

Comment: Password disabled for root. I'm spinning up another instance to work some EBS magic at this point. But I'll keep that in mind, thanks.

Comment: Is `sudo` setup?  You don't need a root password for that, but you do need to have a sudoers file setup.  The distros I can think of off the top of my head that default have no root password usually have a default working sudo.

Comment: Not for the particular user I had. EBS mounting worked its magic though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote from the `sshd_config` manpage:

```
AllowUsers
              This  keyword  can  be followed by a list of user name patterns,
              separated by spaces.  If specified, login is  allowed  only  for
              user  names that match one of the patterns.
```

With this setting, the only user you can log in as is the one you specificed on the `AllowUsers` line. If you can login as this user, and use either `su` or `sudo` to become root, you can regain control of the machine and fix the config file.

If you are using EBS, you can shut this machine down, mount the EBS on a different machine, and fix the config file, and then recreate this VM.

Comment: Thankfully I've never messed up an instance this badly before. I attempted `su` but I realized I didn't have a password set for root. I've never played with EBS before, but looks fairly simple now! Thanks